# Convert csv into xml using XLST transformation?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

This is my  input csv file

```
JobID
123
345
234
121
2390
```

I want the ouput xml file in the below format using XLST transformation

```
<jobs>
    <job>
        <jobid>123</<jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>345</<jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>234</<jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>121</<jobid>
    </job>
    <job>
        <jobid>2390</<jobid>
    </job>
</jobs>
```

Can anyone please help me to solve the sbove problem with some code snippet?

thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't CSV "comma separated values"? I don't see any commas in that text data. So just process `tail(unparsed-text-lines('input.txt'))` and create your `<job><jobid><xsl:value-of select="."/></jobid></job>` for each item.

Comment: Thanks for the update.How can I do it with XSLT 2.0

Comment: Why do you tag the question as [tag:xslt-3.0] to then come back and request a 2.0 solution? If you check the documentation of https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-unparsed-text-lines you can see how to implement it with `tokenize` and `unparsed-text` (which are available in XSLT/XPath 2) and the `tail` call is just another way of using `subsequence(exp, 2)` https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tail

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 3.0 with expand-text="yes" this is simply:

```
<jobs>
  <xsl:for-each select="tail(unparsed-text-lines('input.txt'))">
    <job><jobid>{.}</jobid></job>
  </xsl:for-each>
</jobs>
```

Comment: Hai Michael thanks for the update.How can I do it in XLST 2.0

Comment: Replace `tail(x)` by `remove(x, 1)`, replace `{.}` by `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`, replace `unparsed-text-lines(x)` by `tokenize(unparsed-text(x), '\r?\n'))`

Comment: Thanks a bunch michael